# What do these ( += , -= , *= , /= ) Operators Mean?

Tags: c#, operators

I have been looking everywhere to figure out what these mean and how they are used `+=`, `-=`, `*=`, `/=`, the most I have found is that they are, "Assignment by Addition", "Assignment by Difference", "Assignment by Product", "Assignment by Quotient", etc, but I can't figure out when or how they are used. If anyone can please explain this to me I would be very grateful. thanks

Comment: others you will see: `a++` means `a = a + 1`, `a--` means `a = a - 1`

Comment: A [google search](https://www.google.nl/search?q=c%23+Assignment+by+Addition) for `c# Assignment by Addition` will lead you to the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6z5yhhs(v=vs.80).aspx) describing what it does.

Comment: Consider just using them in a simple application and observing what the result(s) are.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

They are shorthand:

`a += b`

is the same as

`a = a + (b)`

Etc...

so

- `a -= b` is equivalent to `a = a - (b)`
- `a *= b` is equivalent to `a = a * (b)`
- `a /= b` is equivalent to `a = a / (b)`

For the reason why there's a parenthesis over the `b`'s, `a *= 10 / 5` is not equivalent to `a = a * 10 / 5`, but rather equivalent to `a = a * (10 / 5)`

As Kevin Brydon suggested  - Familiarize yourself with the operators in C# [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @IanLundberg It would be worth your while to spend 15 minutes familiarizing yourself with the operators in C# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. It will benefit you in the long run.

Comment: Interesting, but I have a problem with `a *= 13 / 12`. In this case is not equivalent to `a = a * 13 / 12`

Answer (score 6):

See [`7.13 Assignment operators` in the spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691314.aspx) and its subsections., specifically [`7.13.2 Compound assignment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691316.aspx):

> An operation of the form x *op*= y is processed by applying binary operator overload resolution ([Section 7.2.4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691326.aspx)) as if the operation was written x *op* y. Then,
>
> •If the return type of the selected operator is implicitly convertible to the type of x, the operation is evaluated as x = x *op* y, except that x is evaluated only once.
>
> •Otherwise, if the selected operator is a predefined operator, if the return type of the selected operator is explicitly convertible to the type of x, and if y is implicitly convertible to the type of x, then the operation is evaluated as x = (T)(x *op* y), where T is the type of x, except that x is evaluated only once.
>
> •Otherwise, the compound assignment is invalid, and a compile-time error occurs.

Answer (score 5):

These are Assignment operators(Shorthands)

```
a += 1; is equal to a =  a + 1;

b -= 1; is equal to b =  b - 1;

a *= 1; is equal to a =  a * 1;

b /= 1; is equal to b =  b / 1;
```

Refer:[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691314.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

```
a+=1 means a = a+1
a-=2 means a = a-2
a*=3 means a = a*3
a/=4 means a = a/4
```

Answer (score 2):

Roughly, `var *operator*= expression` means `var = var *operator* expression`. Also, I've heard there's a documentation somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

It's a short form. So instead of writing:

x = x + 1;

You can simply write:

x += 1;

It has the same affect.

Answer (score 0):

these are shorthand operators. 
these are used when you does the operation  & stores result into one of the variable between them. that is you store result into one of your operand 
suppose example
 1)x=x+y; 
here you can do x+=y;
ex 2) x=x+1;
here you can do x+=1;